# How to fix 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first' error in Customize MediaController?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

It's almost 4rth day i'm trying to make my own customize mediacontroller. But fail. What i did is Create MyMediaController class and extend MediaController and override all of it's method.

Original MediaController setAnchorView code.

```
public void setAnchorView(View view) {
    if (mAnchor != null) {
        mAnchor.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(mLayoutChangeListener);
    }
    mAnchor = view;
    if (mAnchor != null) {
        mAnchor.addOnLayoutChangeListener(mLayoutChangeListener);
    }

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}
```

MyMediaController setAnchorView code.

```
@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {

    mAnchor = view;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}
```

Another difference is in show method.

Original show method.

```
public void show(int timeout) {
    if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
        setProgress();
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        }
        disableUnsupportedButtons();
        updateFloatingWindowLayout();
        mWindowManager.addView(mDecor, mDecorLayoutParams);
        mShowing = true;
    }
    updatePausePlay();

    // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
    // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
    // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
    post(mShowProgress);

    if (timeout != 0 && !mAccessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
        removeCallbacks(mFadeOut);
        postDelayed(mFadeOut, timeout);
    }
}
```

My show code.

```
 @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
            setProgress();
            if (mPauseButton != null) {
                mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            }

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.BOTTOM
            );

            addView(this, tlp);
            mShowing = true;
        }
        updatePausePlay();

        // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
        // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
        // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
        post(mShowProgress);

        if (timeout != 0 && !mAccessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
            removeCallbacks(mFadeOut);
            postDelayed(mFadeOut, timeout);
        }
    }
```

When addView(this,tlp) method in my show method call. It give error.

```
E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4066)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3916)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3888)
        at com.example.player.MyMediaController.show(MyMediaController.java:361)
        at android.widget.MediaController.show(MediaController.java:417)
```

MyMediaController Class code.

```
public class MyMediaController extends MediaController {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoControllerView";
    MediaController.MediaPlayerControl mPlayer;
    private Context             mContext;
    private View mAnchor;
    private View                mRoot;
    private ProgressBar         mProgress;
    private TextView            mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
    private boolean             mShowing;
    private boolean             mDragging;
    private static final int    sDefaultTimeout = 3000;
    private static final int    FADE_OUT = 1;
    private static final int    SHOW_PROGRESS = 2;
    private boolean             mUseFastForward;
    private boolean             mFromXml;
    private boolean             mListenersSet;
    StringBuilder               mFormatBuilder;
    Formatter                   mFormatter;
    private ImageButton         mPauseButton;
    private ImageButton         mSubtitleButton;
    private ImageButton         mResizeButton;
    private ImageButton         mNextButton;
    private ImageButton         mPrevButton;
    private final AccessibilityManager mAccessibilityManager;

    public MyMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRoot = null;
        mContext = context;
        mUseFastForward = true;
        mFromXml = true;
        mAccessibilityManager = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    }

    public MyMediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
        super(context, useFastForward);
        mUseFastForward = useFastForward;
        mAccessibilityManager = (AccessibilityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    }

    public MyMediaController(Context context) {
        this(context, true);
        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void setMediaPlayer(MediaController.MediaPlayerControl player) {
        mPlayer = player;
        updatePausePlay();
    }


    @Override
    public void setAnchorView(View view) {

        mAnchor = view;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        removeAllViews();
        View v = makeControllerView();
        addView(v, frameParams);
    }

    protected View makeControllerView() {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller_layout, null);

        initControllerView(mRoot);

        return mRoot;
    }

    private void initControllerView(View mRoot) {
        mPauseButton = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.pause);
        if (mPauseButton != null) {
            mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
        }

        mResizeButton = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.resize);
        if (mResizeButton != null) {
            mResizeButton.requestFocus();
            mResizeButton.setOnClickListener(mResizeListener);
        }

        mSubtitleButton = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        if (mSubtitleButton != null)
        {
            mSubtitleButton.requestFocus();
            mSubtitleButton.setOnClickListener(mSubtitleListener);
        }
        mNextButton = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.next);
        if (mNextButton != null ) {
            mNextButton.requestFocus();
            mNextButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
        }
        mPrevButton = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.prev);
        if (mPrevButton != null ) {
            mPrevButton.requestFocus();
            mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);
        }

        mProgress = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
                SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
                seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
            }
            mProgress.setMax(1000);
        }

        mEndTime = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.time);
        mCurrentTime = mRoot.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
        mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    public final View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doPauseResume();
//            show(sDefaultTimeout);
        }
    };

    private void doPauseResume() {
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            mPlayer.start();
        }
        updatePausePlay();
    }

    private void updatePausePlay() {
        if (mRoot == null || mPauseButton == null)
            return;

        if (mPlayer.isPlaying())
            mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        else
            mPauseButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
    }

    public final View.OnClickListener mResizeListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Todo
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Resize is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public final View.OnClickListener mNextListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Todo
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"NextBtn is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public final View.OnClickListener mPrevListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Todo
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"PreviousBtn is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    public final View.OnClickListener mSubtitleListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Todo
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"subtitleBtn is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    private final SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            show(3600000);

            mDragging = true;

            // By removing these pending progress messages we make sure
            // that a) we won't update the progress while the user adjusts
            // the seekbar and b) once the user is done dragging the thumb
            // we will post one of these messages to the queue again and
            // this ensures that there will be exactly one message queued up.
            removeCallbacks(mShowProgress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromuser) {
            if (!fromuser) {
                // We're not interested in programmatically generated changes to
                // the progress bar's position.
                return;
            }

            long duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
            long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
            mPlayer.seekTo( (int) newposition);
            if (mCurrentTime != null)
                mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime( (int) newposition));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            mDragging = false;
            setProgress();
            updatePausePlay();
            show(sDefaultTimeout);

            // Ensure that progress is properly updated in the future,
            // the call to show() does not guarantee this because it is a
            // no-op if we are already showing.
            post(mShowProgress);
        }
    };

    private int setProgress() {
        if (mPlayer == null || mDragging) {
            return 0;
        }
        int position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
        if (mProgress != null) {
            if (duration > 0) {
                // use long to avoid overflow
                long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
                mProgress.setProgress( (int) pos);
            }
            int percent = mPlayer.getBufferPercentage();
            mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent * 10);
        }

        if (mEndTime != null)
            mEndTime.setText(stringForTime(duration));
        if (mCurrentTime != null)
            mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime(position));

        return position;
    }

    private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
        int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

        int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

        mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
        if (hours > 0) {
            return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
        } else {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
        }
    }

    private final Runnable mShowProgress = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int pos = setProgress();
            if (!mDragging && mShowing && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                postDelayed(mShowProgress, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void show(int timeout) {
        if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
            setProgress();
            if (mPauseButton != null) {
                mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            }

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.BOTTOM
            );

            addView(this, tlp);
            mShowing = true;
        }
        updatePausePlay();

        // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
        // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
        // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
        post(mShowProgress);

        if (timeout != 0 && !mAccessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
            removeCallbacks(mFadeOut);
            postDelayed(mFadeOut, timeout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isShowing() {
        return mShowing;
    }

    /**
     * Remove the controller from the screen.
     */
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        if (mAnchor == null)
            return;

        if (mShowing) {
            try {
                removeCallbacks(mShowProgress);
                removeView(this);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                Log.w("MediaController", "already removed");
            }
            mShowing = false;
        }
    }

    private final Runnable mFadeOut = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                show(0);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                show(sDefaultTimeout);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                hide();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

When i change `View mAnchor` variable to `ViewGroup mAnchor` and then change show method to following and use it with surfaceView then it works. But i want to use it with VideoView so i can't make `View mAnchor` to `ViewGroup mAnchor`.

```
 public void show(int timeout) {
        if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
            setProgress();
            if (mPauseButton != null) {
                mPauseButton.requestFocus();
            }

            FrameLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.BOTTOM
            );

            mAnchor.addView(this, tlp);
            mShowing = true;
        }
        updatePausePlay();

        // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
        // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
        // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
        post(mShowProgress);

        if (timeout != 0 && !mAccessibilityManager.isTouchExplorationEnabled()) {
            removeCallbacks(mFadeOut);
            postDelayed(mFadeOut, timeout);
        }
    }
```

I know it should give error. But didn't know how to resolve it. If someone think i did it wrong plz give me suggestion, how i should do it. I didn't want to use customize mediacontroller with surfaceView. I want to use it with VideoView. I really need help.